# CSS Related: Trying to position a div styled to look like a bar on a wepage

Tags: jquery, css, layout

I'm trying to position a div tag on my page absolutely so no matter if you resize the page or not the div does not move position. . I've used absolute positioning in both the div tag  and in some JQuery .css({position:absolute}),
It still moves when i resize the screen. quite annoying.

Comment: I think position:absolute should be fine. Need to see the code.

Comment: Is your div the child of "body"?

Comment: you know it is, that maybe why.. i have to make it the child of the area i want to position it right, in this case its a TR  from a table . .?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [position: fixed](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html) however that is not supported by IE 6 and lower so you have to apply some tricks to make [position: fixed work in IE](http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/);

Comment: @graphicdivine thanks for the clarifying edit, nearly have the rep to help that way myself!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, it sounds like you need `position: fixed`

Position absolute will position the element absolutely within its parent (more or less), and will still move when the page is scrolled.

Position fixed will position the element at the same place within the window, no matter whether you scroll or not.

Show us what you have, because I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: $("#dataBar1").html($("<div><a href='#PP class='P'> " + sw+ "</a></div>")).css({
                    position: 'static',
                    left: (sDate1.left) + "px",
                    top: (sDate1.top + topPos) + "px",
                    width: (eDate1.left - sDate1.left) + 25 + "px"
                }).addClass("option1");

I tried static and it keeps it in a position, however not the postion based on my properties

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'fixed' not 'static'

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
position: fixed
```